# How can I make an int second counter that starts when a button is pressed in update()?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a second counter that runs in GameScene.update() and counts when I press a button up to 5 seconds, then stops and resets to 0 waiting for another button press.

Here is my if button is pressed code:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (Data.gameScene.buttonPressed == true) {
        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship2")
        player.physicsBody = nil
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the button is pressed, the player goes invisible (Spaceship2 is low opacity) and it no longer has a physics body (so enemies can't hit it).

What I want to have is this (in pseudo code):

```
if (button pressed == true) {
    start timer
    if timer < 5 seconds { 
        player can't be hit and is invisible
    } else {
         player can be hit and is visible
      }
 }
```

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a sequence of a wait action and a runBlock action.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (Data.gameScene.buttonPressed == true) {
        //put code to make the player invisible

       let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)
       let makePlayerVisibleAction = SKAction.runBlock {
           //put code to make the player visible
       }
       let action = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, makePlayerVisibleAction])

       player.runAction(action)  
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Almost works properly! My issue is now my way of making the player invisible as I am making the player physics body nil. When I reenable it, collision won't work anymore. Do you know a batter way of hiding the player so it won't collide?

Comment: Don't worry @akmidd I ended up changing the player category bit mask to the enemy for the 5 seconds, then back to the player.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a timer which fires after 5 seconds:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: NStimer?
    var timerIsRunning = false

    func buttonPressed() {
        if timerIsRunning {
            return
        }

        // start the timer
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        self.timerIsRunning = true

        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship2")
        player.physicsBody = nil
    }

    func update() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timerIsRunning = false

        ...
    }

}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, where would I call buttonPressed?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `update` function is called on a regular basis, and conveniently provides a time stamp (in seconds), you can simply save the time stamp when the button is pressed, and use that to determine when the 5 seconds is finished.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (Data.gameScene.buttonPressed == true) {
        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship2")
        player.physicsBody = nil
        player.isInvisible = true
        player.startInvisible = currentTime
    }
    else if (player.isInvisible){
        if (currentTime - player.startInvisible > 5) {
            player.isInvisible = false
            player.texture = ...
            player.physicsBody = ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! However player.isInvisible and player.startInvisible both don't exist in SKSpriteNode. Are you assuming these are already custom functions?

Comment: @DanTdd I was assuming that you would create a subclass of SKSpriteNode that has additional properties. This would allow multiple game objects to go into invisible mode simultaneously (each with its own timestamp). However, if only one node (the player's ship) is allowed to be invisible, then the properties could be properties of the SKScene.

Comment: Hmm not quite sure what you mean by that :( It's my first game and i'm pretty new to it all. can't get it to work